# How is an algebraic plane curve encoded in the quotient of the power series ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k[[x,y]]$ be the ring of formal power series with coefficients in $k$, where $k$ is an algebraically closed field. Let $f\in k[x,y]$ be a polynomial in two variables. From $f$ we get an algebraic plane curve as the locus of the points which satisfy $f(x,y)=0$.

My questions now are: How is this algebraic plane curve encoded in $R:=k[[x,y]]/(f)$, how does this look like when we choose the complex numbers for $k$ and is the set of points satisfying $f(x,y)=0$ an (maximal) ideal in R?

Comment: Hmm, I don't think the plane curve is "encoded" in $R$, in the sense that $R$ would determine $f$. For a simple example, if $f = 1+x$ then $f$ defines a line. But $1+x$ is a unit in $k[[x,y]]$, so $R = 0$. We get the same $R=0$ for any other curve not passing through the origin. So $R$ doesn't determine $f$. Perhaps you meant something else?

Comment: Hmm, okay. But what if $f$ is not a unit. Let's say $f$ is $x^2-y^2$. The algebraic plane curve belonging to $f$ looks like two lines crossing through the origin. Does $R:=k[[x,y]]/(f)$ also "look" like this?

Comment: or does the algebraic plane curve and his form tell me anything about R?

Comment: Note that $\operatorname{Spec} k[[x,y]]$ is a single point, an "infinitesimal neighborhood" of the origin in $k^2 = \operatorname{Spec} k[x,y]$. So $k[[x,y]]/(f)$ sort of "can't see" anything away from the origin. For a more explicit example, I claim that $k[[x,y]](y^2-x^2)$ is isomorphic to $k[[x,y]]/(y^2-x^2(x+1))$. Let $p(x) = (x^2+x^3)^{1/2}$, expanded as a formal power series (using binomial theorem). Then the map $k[[x,y]] \to k[[x,y]]$ given by $x \mapsto p(x)$, $y \mapsto y$, is an automorphism, which gives an isomorphism between the quotient rings.

Comment: The plane curve tells you the analytic isomorphism class of $R$. If, e.g., $f$ is nonsingular at the origin, $R$ is just a power series ring in one variable. Completing destroys all "global" information such as genus, and even irreducibility as the previous comment indicates.